# Entity Framework 5 - RETURN(X) from a Stored Procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

The last line of my stored procedure is this:

```
RETURN (22);
```

I am calling my stored procedure as follows:

```
var result = new ObjectParameter("result", typeof(double));
int success = context.MySP(code, Id, result);
```

The stored procedure works fine when called from my code.

`code` is a string, `Id` is a Guid and `result` is an `OUTPUT` parameter and works fine.

So I know the `RETURN (22);` statement is being reached (running in query analyser confirms this too, the return value is 22 when I run it there).

I was expecting (in this example), that `success` would contain 22, but it **always** contains -1.

What is the most straightforward way to get the `22` return value into the `success` variable?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure should have an output declared.  Assuming it is `@result`, you will need to set it and return it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP
    /*
    Input parameters here
    */
    @result INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET @result = 22
    return @result

END
```

The return value of your call should be in `result`.

```
var result = new ObjectParameter("result", typeof(double));
context.MySP(code, Id, result);

int success = result.Value;
```

Comment: So you are saying it's not actually possible to get the RETURN(X) value?  Sure I can make "success" another OUTPUT value, but I thought I could just use the RETURN value.

Comment: It IS possible, but you need to explicitly set the value of your output variable `@result` in your stored procedure, and return it.  Then in your client code, your `ObjectParameter`'s `Value` property will be the result of the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I see I need to create another OUTPUT parameter for "success" and RETURN (@Success) from within my SP.  The only issue with that, is that RETURN (22) probably won't end up putting 22 in my "success' variable?  I was hoping to get the actual RETURN value regardless of how it was returned.

Comment: Jeff... Note Result and Success are two entirely different things.  Sorry if there was confusion.

Comment: Correct on the `RETURN(22)` comment.  You will need to `RETURN @Success`.

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote and checkbox my response if it has answered your question.